# How to create udf containing Array (case class) for complex column in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which have a complex column datatype of Arraytype>. For transforming this dataframe I have created udf  which can consume this column using Array [case class] as parameter. The main bottle neck here is when I create case class according to stucttype, the structfield name contains special characters for example "##field". So I provide same name to case class like this way case class (`##field`) and attach this to udf parameter. After interpreted in spark udf definition change name of case class field to this "$hash$hashfield". When performing transform using this dataframe it is failing because of this miss match. Please help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due JVM limitations Scala stores identifiers in encoded form and currently Spark can't map `##field` to `$hash$hashfield`.

One possible solution is to extract fields manually from raw row (but you need to know order of the fields in `df`, you can use `df.schema` for that):

```
val myUdf = udf { (struct: Row) =>
  // Pattern match struct:
  struct match {
    case Row(a: String) => Foo(a)
  }

  // .. or extract values from Row
  val `##a` = struct.getAs[String](0)
}
```